# jQuery flip with fading

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a flip animation that will fade out until the flip reach the middle of the flip animation and fade in from that point until the flip animation ends.
This is what I got so far, but not what I am trying to achieve:

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bddz9j8h/1/)

HTML:

```
<button onclick="flip()">flip the card</button>
<section class="container">
  <div class="card" onclick="flip()">
    <div class="front">1</div>
    <div class="back">2</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 260px;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    -webkit-perspective: 800px;
    -moz-perspective: 800px;
    -o-perspective: 800px;
    perspective: 800px;
}
.card {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 3s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 3s;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 3s;
    transition: transform 3s;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
.card div {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 260px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 140px;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.card .front {
  background: red;
}
.card .back {
    background: blue;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    transform: rotateY( 180deg );
}
.card.flipped {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    transform: rotateY( 180deg );
}
```

JS:

```
function flip() {
    $('.card').toggleClass('flipped').fadeOut(1500).fadeIn(1500);
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try fiddling with the `fadeIn`/`fadeOut` times: `$('.card').toggleClass('flipped').fadeOut(750).fadeIn(750);` ? You may want to try different times

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc  tried it, didn't work, but below answers do. Thanks tho :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make CSS transition with same speed using "transition-timing-function" and use fadeTo() instead of fadeOut() and fadeIn() in jQuery.

CSS:

```
.card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 3s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 3s;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 3s;
  transition: transform 3s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear; /* Safari and Chrome */
  transition-timing-function: linear;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function flip() {    
  $('.card').toggleClass('flipped').fadeTo(1500,0,function(){ $(this).fadeTo(1500,1);});
}
```

Code Snippet:

```js
function flip() {    
    $('.card').toggleClass('flipped').fadeTo(1500,0,function(){ $(this).fadeTo(1500,1);});
}
```

```css
.container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 260px;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    -webkit-perspective: 800px;
    -moz-perspective: 800px;
    -o-perspective: 800px;
    perspective: 800px;
}
.card {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 3s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 3s;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 3s;
    transition: transform 3s;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear; /* Safari and Chrome */
    transition-timing-function: linear;
}
.card div {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 260px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 140px;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.card .front {
  background: red;
}
.card .back {
    background: blue;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    
}
.card.flipped {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    transform: rotateY( 180deg );    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="flip()">flip the card</button>
<section class="container">
  <div class="card" onclick="flip()">
    <div class="front">1</div>
    <div class="back">2</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for. Kind of iPhone dialer flip animation ;)

Answer (score 1):

By default, the [`transition-timing-function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-timing-function) is set to `ease`. If you want it to be `linear`, you can add the following to your css:

```
transition-timing-function: linear;
```

**[See Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bddz9j8h/3/)**

If you want to keep it at `ease`, you need to calculate the "halfway point" using the [ease formula](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/timing-function#ease). It reaches the halfway point around ~25% of the way through. You can modify your time accordingly:

```
$('.card').toggleClass('flipped').fadeOut(750).fadeIn(2250);
```

**[See Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bddz9j8h/4/)**

Comment: I upvoted your answer for the good explanation, although if you look at your fiddles you will see that the result, for some reason, still isn't the one I was trying to achieve (the flipped side just fades in without flipping)....